# Using string variables as a path to access other variables in AS 2

Tags: flash, path, actionscript-2

i'm making a simple fighting game in flash, using actionscript 2 (i know as3 is way better, but changing now is not an option, my next project will be in as3 i swear).

The thing is this, i have a "Player" object, which attaches a movieclip with named either "player1" or "player2" upon being instantiated, depending on a given parameter. The proper instance name is stored in a variable called PlayerName. For example:

```
var character:Player = new Player(1);
```

This code will create a Player object. Because of the number "1", the constructor will set the PlayerName variable to the string "player1". Finally, the constructor should also attach a movieclip named "player1" to root.

I solved the naming of the attached movieclip doing this:

```
_root.attachMovie(ID, this["PlayerName"], _root.getNextHighestDepth());
```

Now with a similar idea, i want to solve the following problem (this is my question): say i want to move my recently spawned movieclip (or access any of its properties), how do i use the string PlayerName in the path to the MC? My intuition would be to do this:

```
_root.PlayerName._x +=1;
```

or

```
 _root.(this["PlayerName"])._x +=1;
```

Hoping that when flash compiled, this["PlayerName"] would turn into the stored String, but this obviously doesn't work. I'm really stuck here, i used to do this all the time in PHP, i mean, if this were PHP i'd use this:

```
_root.$PlayerName._x +=1;
```

Any suggestions? How can you make this work? I can think of a few workarounds, namely, storing a reference to the clip when attaching it:

```
clip = _root.attachMovie(....
```

And then accessing its properties through clip (clip._x +=1), but i'd feel more comfortable if i knew how to do this using the variable in the route like in PHP.. not that i care too much, it's just that in other situations this "clip" workaround may not work.

Please bear in mind that i'm kinda new to OOP in action script, haha, maybe this is completely crazy and people do this some other way.

thank you for your time!

Comment: hey i made a download manager in as2 that stores strings and then uses them for the file path, http://ffiles.com/flash/web_applications_and_data/download_manager_16slots_3567.html all the source code is included.. Basically the text file has strings of paths then flash reads these paths into vars to goto the download link... browse through it it should be at use.

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to use the "x" as this is the position not the character [NAME] it self.

```
  _root.PlayerName._x +=1; //dont need the x value
```

Try something like:

```
     _root.PlayerName +"1"; //from memory should =: PlayerName1

     trace("player"+1);// just type this as a test
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found how to do it, thanks anyway. Should anybody else come across this with the same doubt, this is how you do it:

To tell flash that you will use the STRING inside a variable as the path, you need to use square brackets. Now this can get a little confusing, at least for me, beacause when you use the brackets, you are not supposed to use a dot. You would think, if the variable is called PlayerName and the path to de MC's property is _root.PlayerName._x , that the syntax would be:

```
_root.[PlayerName]._x +=1;
```

But this is WRONG and does not work. At least this is what i've gathered so far. Now, to make it work, you need to get rid of the dot before the first bracket, after the second one it's okay. Not sure if this is correct, but it does seem to work, give it a try:

```
_root[PlayerName]._x +=1;
```

This does effectively work, it accesses the _x property of the movieclip named "whatever-is-inside-the-PlayerName-variable" and increments it by 1. The reason i found this confusing is because as there's no dot after root, it looks as though you were accessing the root variable as if it were an array, and that would make no sense since PlayerName wasn't stored in root.... anyway, i'm not sure how or why, but this appears to work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`_root[variableName]._x` is the correct way to use a variable in a path.